# Fail to open excel file using Process.Start() in .Net4.0

Tags: c#, .net, excel, process.start

Recently an old project of .Net 1.1 is migrating to .Net4.0. The project is using the following method to open excel file:

```
Process process = new Process();

try
{
  process.StartInfo.FileName = marco_file;
  process.Start();
}
catch(Exception)
{
}
finally
{
  process.Close();
}
```

And the marco_file is the path of excel file with macros, like "C:\project\test.xls"
The macro in it will run immediately when the excel file open.

In .Net1.1 both the codes and the macro runs well. In .Net4, the codes runs without exceptions. But the macro didn't work.

Why the macro in the excel file didn't run?

My environment is Win7 64bit. Office 2010 64bit. IIS 7.5

Thanks

When I change to the following codes and run the debug mode

```
process.StartInfo.FileName = marco_file;
if (process.Start())
{
    Debug.WriteLine("-->start ");
}
else
{
    Debug.WriteLine("-->failed ");
}
```

The result is that it goes into the else block, which means the process fails to start.

Any one knows why?

Comment: Are you sure your code is running without any exceptions?  You seem to be eating them.

Comment: Remove the catch{} and try again so you can see if an exception is thrown and what it is.

Comment: try writing it as catch(Exception ex) { // print exception } instead of just catch(Exception)

Comment: The problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

Check the security in Excel.  By default Excel 2010 will disable Macros when you open a workbook containing them, and you have to explicitly enable them.

To enable macros you need to go to:

```
File tab on the ribbon => Options
                       => Trust Center
                       => Trust Center Settings...
                       => Macro Settings
```

The only option here that will allow the macro to run automatically is:

```
Enable all macros (not recommended; potentially dangerous code can run)
```

Note the warning, though.

Comment: The security setting is the lowest. Enable all the macros

Comment: Does the macro run automatically if you open the file directly?

Comment: Yes. It runs automatically if I open

Comment: Does your code open the file and not run the macro, or not open the file at all?